# How to host a static s3 website with cloudfront that uses cognito built in login pages

Tags: web, amazon-s3, static, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

I am beginner to aws. I want to host a static S3 website with cloudfront distribution but I want to add the cognito built in login page first when user hit the website url.I am not sure how to do that. I am seeing multiple solutions for S3 + cloudfront or cognito but I am not getting any solution as to how to integrate S3 website + cloudfront + cognito bult in page.
Can someone please suggest how to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might get better help asking for pointers to online tutorials or examples of adding authentication to  static site.  If you really want someone to help show you how to do it on your site, post (a snippet of) the current page from that site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend looking into AWS Amplify (https://aws-amplify.github.io/) which is very much like AWS's answer to Firebase. It allows you to very quickly spin up AWS resources such as Cognito, Storage (including for websites) with S3, apis, databases and much more.

AWS Amplify has a ready-made and configurable Authenticator component for both React and Angular projects that integrates with Cognito and will immediately handle sign ups, log ins, password reset etc.

- For Angular (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular) see the Authenticator component.
- For React (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react) see Add Auth.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

CloudFront doesn't have native Cognito integration, at least as of this writing.

CloudFront does, however, have a feature called [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) that allows you to provide server-side JavaScript that CloudFront can execute at specific trigger points during HTTP request (and response) processing, allowing the code to examine aspects of requests (and responses) and then tell CloudFront to modify how things are processed, such as allowing or denying requests based on certain criteria (such as for authentication purposes).

The AWS Blog post [How to Use Lambda@Edge and JSON Web Tokens to Enhance Web Application Security](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-how-to-use-lambdaedge-and-json-web-tokens-to-enhance-web-application-security/) appears to describe in detail how you can use Lambda@Edge to roll your own Cognito-based solution, and includes a CloudFormation stack template that will actually launch this solution in your own AWS account, where you can then examine the code and configuration, to see how it all works.

With this setup, CloudFront can use a standard [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) to authenticate itself when making requests to the S3 bucket, so S3 doesn't need any special configuration -- S3 will be unaware of the Cognito authentication occurring on the front-end.

Comment: For a newer (but basically the same) approach from AWS, see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-using-cookies-protect-your-amazon-cloudfront-content-from-being-downloaded-by-unauthenticated-users/